# Assembly - the effect on EAX by AL

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I'm aware that the following code:

```
MOV AL, 8 ;
```

will put the value 8 (decimal) into the lowest byte of EAX. However, if EAX already has the decimal value 1 stored therein, what happens, does it overwrite it?

So...

```
XOR EAX, EAX ;
INC EAX ; 
MOV AL, 8 ;
```

Does EAX now just contain the decimal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it copies and replaces the destination operand with the source operand, the source operand is unchanged.

Comment: ok great, i just didnt know whether when incrementing EAX where the value 1 would go within the 4 bytes, i.e. high, low or otherwise. Assume it always gets pushed onto the lowest byte unless otherwise specified

Comment: To clarify, if the 1 was put into EAX's highest order byte first it would equal   0001 0000 0000 0000 which is 4096 decimal so it has to be put into the lowest byte (AL) 0001 which is replaced by 1000 = 8

Comment: where is the default when you INC EAX, is it low order?

Comment: Yes the INC EAX instruction would be the equivalent of ADD EAX,1

Comment: @NhatMLe Your __To clarify__ comment is wrong! A 1 in __EAX's__ highest order byte would yield 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000. This is much larger than 4096 decimal.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Source: wwwi10.lrr.in.tum.de/~jasmin/basics.html]

When EAX contains 1, the higher bytes contain 0 and AL 1 - that's the number representation in a 32 bits integer. When moving 8 in AL, EAX has still the three other bytes with 0 and the whole integer is 8 now.